# Display approval sign/check mark (✓) on Kivy Label

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on a Kivy(Python) Project and I need to display approval(✓) and cross(X) symbol in different scenario. I can display cross symbol but unable to display other one. Is there any way to do this ? Thanks.

***Note:*** I have tried, writing **text:'✓'** and **text:u'2713'** under Label in .kv file but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is displayed instead of the check mark?

Comment: A box like this []. I think current fonts doesn't support's this approval mark that's why it shows empty box. Is there any font which support approval symbol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font supplied with Kivy doesn't include the tick mark. You need to use fonts that include those symbols. Tick is available in fonts Arial Unicode MS, Wingdings and Wingdings 2. You can download the font ttf file and have it in the same folder with your script.

Link to download the font
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/88978/arial-unicode-ms

Then include the font and use it in the label as follow:

```
Label:
   font_name:'arial-unicode-ms.ttf'
   text: "This is the tick ✓"
```

Comment: Thanks @Abu Raid!  Exactly, I was looking for font which supports tick mark. Let me try this.

Comment: Hi @Abu Raid, arial-unicode-ms.ttf doesn't work. Tick mark is not available in its character map.

Comment: Thanks @Abu Raid, There was encoding issue as well. I have resolved that issue and updated your answer. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Bro I was also troubling from same problem from morning but now I figured it out actually so I would like to share it with you.I used below code:

```
        def wrong_btn(self):
    self.ids.wrong_button.text =    u"⌫"       self.ids.wrong_button.font_name=r"C:\Users\95532\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\Arial-Unicode-MS.ttf"
```

I used this to specify the folder in which the font is stored so you can also download the font you want and just specify the path and don't forget use a r i.e raw string mark or else it wont work I wasted my whole day searching for that hope this helps you bro